# Handling authentication/authorization: ASP.NET Core Web Application => ASP.NET Core Web API => SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to work out the best way to handle authentication for a new external web application  and web service application using ASP.NET Core. Here is the general setup:

1. Username/password is stored in SQL Server database
2. Web application ONLY makes call to web service
3. Web service (Web API) makes calls to database and returns data to web application

So the idea is that the user logs in once and using the built-in cookies authentication provider will stay logged in. However, I want to pass that authentication token or whatever to the web service application and have whatever it does run under the appropriate security context for that user. I've looked for examples that resemble this design but haven't found a good one. Could anyone make any high-level recommendations or point me to some helpful resources on how I can achieve this design?

Answer (score 0):

Take asp.net core MVC and web api as an example, put the login page in the web application. Put cookie authentication in web api. After the user logs in, it applies for a token through the web api, and the token will be stored in the cookie cache of the browser.
Here is the cookie configuration. In Startup.cs (web api).

```
services.AddAuthentication("scheme")
            .AddCookie("scheme", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "authname";
                
            });
```

If the token is successfully applied, it will be written in browser.

[image]

Then I add a action that gets the cookie tocken.

```
    [Route("getTocken")]
    public string getTocken( )
    {
        string cookie =""; 
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("authname", out 
        cookie);
        
        return cookie;
    }
```

This is the result.

[image]

This cookie tocken could be saved in session for maintaining state.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this was helpful to me. Thank you :)